# Sagan's Parametrization for the von Koch Curve

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, fractals

In **1** Hans Sagan provides a parametrization for the von Koch curve and a proof for the continuity of such parametrization. The parametrization is done by dividing the triangle of vertices $\lbrace (0,0),\ (1,0),\ (1/2,\sqrt{3}/6)\rbrace$ into four squares at each iteration as is done [here](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/KnoppsOsgoodCurveConstruction/) and providing a total order on the triangles created at a given iteration for every iteration. Then, he claims:

> Now,
> we define the coordinates of the point on the von Koch curve that corresponds to
> the parameter value $t\in \mathcal{J}$ as follows: if $t$ is one of the partitition points, its image
> $f(t)$ shall be the corresponding nodal point. Otherwise, $t$ is uniquely determined by
> a sequence of nested closed intervals of lenths $1/4^n$ (the intervals of the partitions)
> to which, in turn, there corresponds a unique sequence of closed nested triangular
> regions with diameters $1/3^n$ that defines a unique point $f(t)\in E^2$. Conversely, with
> every point $P$ on the von Koch curve, there corresponds a unique pre-image $t\in \mathcal{J}$:
> if $P$ lies on the von Koch curve and is a nodal point, then its unique pre-image in
> $\mathcal{J}$ is the point common to the two intervals that correspond to the two triangles.
> Otherwise, $P$ is uniquely determined by a sequence of nested closed triangular
> regions that shrink into $P$ to which there corresponds a unique sequence of nested
> closed intervals that shrink into the unique pre-image of $P$. The mapping is
> continuous: if $|t_1- t_2| < 1/4^n$, then, $t_1,t_2$ lie, at worst, in two adjacent subintervals of
> length $1/4^n$ each and, their images $f(t_1),f(t_2)$ lie, at worst, in two adjacent triangles
> of diameter $1/3^n$ each. Hence, $|f(t_1) -f(t_2)| < 2/3^n$.

Could anyone please explain to me why does his reasoning proof that $f$ is continuous?

Thank you in advance for your anskwers!

**REFERENCES**

**1** Hans Sagan (1994) The taming of a monster: a parametrization of the von Koch Curve, International Journal of Mathematical Education in Science and Technology, 25:6, 869-877, DOI: 10.1080/0020739940250612

Comment: One needs to show:
$$\forall t_1. \forall \epsilon. \exists \delta. \forall t_2. |t_1 - t_2| < \delta \implies |f(t_1) - f(t_2)| < \epsilon$$  Which parts of the argument are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Claude I had trouble precisely because I didn't see that by his choosing of the $\delta$ he was already choosing every posible one (and the same for the $\epsilon$). Thank you for your comment!

Comment: ah I see the issue now - he chooses $\delta$ and gets $\epsilon$, it might be more work to show it the other direction (which is what is necessary to show continuity). thanks for pointing it out!